# Maven retry dependency download if failed

Tags: java, maven

During downloading dependencies by maven, one of it fails due to network issues:

```
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-failsafe-plugin/2.16/maven-failsafe-plugin-2.16.pom
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:2.16 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:jar:2.16
```

I would like to retry it for `n` times where `n` will be configurable. How can I do this?

Answer (score 12):

I had a similar problem in Gitlab CI/CD. This seems to have resolved the issue:

```
-Dmaven.wagon.http.retryHandler.count=3
```

> Since version 3.2, the retry handler can be configured with system
> properties:
>
> ...
>
> - - `maven.wagon.http.retryHandler.count` = number of retries for default or standard implementations.

Other HTTP client settings are described here: https://maven.apache.org/wagon/wagon-providers/wagon-http/

**Edit:** As keiki pointed out in the comments, `3` appears to be the default, so it's not clear how setting this value would help. Please comment with your experience.

Comment: As 3 is the default value I doubt that setting will help. Or what am I missing?

Comment: @keiki can you link docs showing that `3` is the default value? Because, I agree, that would mean this "solution" is suspect. (Though with 7 upvotes, that seems kinda unlikely?)

Comment: I just looked into the source code tbh. I didn't find an official documentation to the defaults. https://github.com/apache/maven-wagon/blob/1a90ecc5819ee3e146ba0769e6488579d865de16/wagon-providers/wagon-http-shared/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/wagon/shared/http/AbstractHttpClientWagon.java#L434

Yet maybe I'm missing something (e.g. subclass overriding this default)

Comment: @keiki that's wild. Added a comment to the answer to solicit more samples. Maybe that'll help get to the bottom of it.

Comment: weird answer, as it does not solve anything

Comment: @Eugene even weirder that it keeps getting upvoted. :-P

Comment: In case someone wonder why this don't work anymore: Starting with Maven 3.9.0 release, the default transport (the default transport used by Maven Resolver) changed from ancient Wagon to modern maven-resolver-transport-http aka native HTTP transport.

Comment: @GiovanniToraldo is there a new fix that works for maven-resolver-transport-http I can link to?

Answer (score 10):

Maven seems to have an issue with fetching dependencies due to keep-alive connections being closed. This happens when you are running `mvn` in a build-environment (Docker, Azure, Jenkins) and the build is rather long (> 5 minutes).

Use this maven flag to disable keep-alive for HTTP requests and see if it fixes your problem:

```
-Dhttp.keepAlive=false
```

Others have mentioned using this flag as well:

```
-Dmaven.wagon.http.pool=false
```

For example

```
mvn -Dhttp.keepAlive=false -Dmaven.wagon.http.pool=false clean package
```

[Source of the original solution for azure](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/357696/maven-project-build-failing-with-connection-reset.html)

Comment: It's early to tell for sure but it looks like the `http.keepAlive` suggestion has gotten our team past a reoccurring issue with a specific dependency resolution issue. We'd still like to get to the bottom of why the issue started happening in general, perhaps a network issue or something but the `-X` option didn't really seem to give us the necessary insight to dig any further.

Comment: jpierson - let me know if you find out why it is happening. I am curious about the cause of the connection reset as well.

Answer (score 5):

In the case that you are running in an environment behind a NAT, with a short NAT timeout, one possibility is to set `-Dmaven.wagon.httpconnectionManager.ttlSeconds=25` and `-Daether.connector.http.connectionMaxTtl=25` (Maven 3.9+) instead of disabling the http connection pooling in maven.

This is used in apache/pulsar repository:

```yaml
env:
  MAVEN_OPTS: -Dmaven.wagon.httpconnectionManager.ttlSeconds=25 -Dmaven.wagon.http.retryHandler.count=3 -Daether.connector.http.connectionMaxTtl=25
```

In the [last comment of WAGON-545](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WAGON-545?focusedCommentId=16755035&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-16755035), it says "Azure users shall set the TTL to 240 seconds or less."

Comment: For me 30 seconds helped. 45 didn't. It depends solely on infrastructure. So you may need to expirement a good value yourself.

Comment: In Apache Pulsar, it was necessary to completely disable pooling. the current MAVEN_OPTS in use are 
`-Dhttp.keepAlive=false -Dmaven.wagon.http.pool=false -Dmaven.wagon.http.retryHandler.class=standard -Dmaven.wagon.http.retryHandler.count=3`

Comment: For fixing some artifact download issues, it might be necessary to upgrade the Maven Wagon HTTP library. This solution was necessary in Apache Pulsar: https://github.com/apache/pulsar/pull/9883/files#diff-1dde1dd0c711d85ba5031a48b8ddfe78fe788cf5eece9dd438a7a901e7a5edb2

Comment: Maven 3.8.1 contains the updated Maven Wagon HTTP library version 3.4.3 , that fixes some issues.

Comment: @LariHotari just to confirm, is `MAVEN_OPTS` the correct place to put this? Maven's documentation says that `MAVEN_OPTS` is for arguments passed to the underlying JVM - are these the right kind of arguments for that?

Comment: @JohnBergqvist These are arguments that need to be passed to the underlying JVM. The solution is in use in the GitHub Action CI for apache/pulsar repository.

Comment: Maven doesn't use Wagon by default any more, but rather Aether. That means you *probably* need to set `-Daether.connector.http.connectionMaxTtl=25` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Let me suggest an alternative solution:

Set up a Nexus or Artifactory server in your local network. Let your builds run through it. It will cache all the artifacts that were used so that the risk of running into network problems dramatically decreases.

Comment: Well, we've got Nexus server in our local network and still there is this problem. So for me the easiest solution will be to just retry downloading.

Comment: So the problem is with the connection of the Nexus to the outside world?

Comment: It might be, but TBH I would like to just retry from maven if it's possible. I haven't got access to Nexus server on my own.

Comment: I understand, but it is probably is _not_ possible (I am not sure, though). It might be more sensible, though, to search for the original network problem. I never experienced any failed downloads from MavenCentral.

Answer (score 2):

If this is in a long-ish build in a recent enough Maven (3.9 or later) and you're doing this because of a build on Azure (e.g., inside Github Actions using the standard runners) then you're hitting a problem with stale connections; there's a firewall in Azure that *silently* drops long-lived inactive connections, and anything idle for over half a minute or so is at risk from it. There are other solutions above, but they don't work because Maven now uses the Aether library for HTTP connections instead of Wagon.

The fix I've now got deployed in my code is to set a system property for the Java code with `-Daether.connector.http.connectionMaxTtl=25`. This seems to do the trick. (As you can see from looking through [this page](https://maven.apache.org/resolver/configuration.html), Aether will retry connections three times by default. That *isn't* helpful inside Azure, but is in other situations.)

---

**Within a Github Actions workflow,** the easiest way of passing this in is via a top-level `env` setup in your workflow file so that it is applied to all calls to Maven:

```yaml
env:
  MAVEN_OPTS: >
    -Daether.connector.http.connectionMaxTtl=25
```

(If you have other things you're putting into `MAVEN_OPTS` then you'll need to merge things. I find the above a good and readable way to do it, with one system property per line.)